# Why encrypt with aspnet_regiis.exe

Tags: asp.net, encryption, web-config, aspnet-regiis.exe

I want to encrypt my web.config file to hide some sensitive data like passwords with [aspnet_regiis](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gaurav/2013/12/15/encrypting-section-of-config-file-using-aspnet_regiis-exe-the-configuration-for-physical-path-web-config-cannot-be-opened/).

Encryption is made with this code in the command prompt `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "appSettings" C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testweb`

And I can decrypt it with this code *(-pef changed to -pdf)*

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis.exe -pdf "appSettings" C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testweb`

So my question is: Why should I even encrypt the file when it's so easy for anyone to decrypt it with above command? There is no "key" needed to encrypt/decrypt.

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Some hackers may steal the web.config but cannot access to the cmd.exe.